# Load partial view in main view on click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get a partial view to load on my current view when the user clicks the link but it keeps loading the partial view rather then on the same view.

Not sure what I'm missing.

Main View Controller

```
    public PartialViewResult MonitorDetail(MonitorType mType)
    {
        return PartialView("MonitorDetail", mType);
    }
```

Main View

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<p class="lbutton radius">
    @Ajax.ActionLink("SQL Cluster Online ", "MonitorDetail", "NOCCon", MonitorType.AHSSQLCluster, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "monitorDetail" })
    <span class="lbutton-addition @(Model.SQLClusterOnline ? "online" : "offline")">
        @(Model.SQLClusterOnline ? "Online" : "Offline")
    </span></p>

<div id="monitorDetail"></div>
```

Partial View

```
@model PAL.Intranet.MonitorType
<div>
    You choose @Model.ToString()
</div>
```

Also keeps telling me mType is null but i'm passing it MonitorType in the ActionLink so I added it as nullable so I can try and figure out the first issue and then work on the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its displaying only the partial view, its because you have not included the required files for `Ajax.ActionLink` to work (and its just performing a normal redirect). Ensure you have included `jquery.{version}.js` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

The reason parameter `mType` is null is because you are not passing a value. It should be

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("SQL Cluster Online ", "MonitorDetail", "NOCCon", new { mtype = MonitorType.AHSSQLCluster }, new AjaxOptions() ....)
```

Comment: That corrected the null issue but still doing a normal redirect. Updated code.

Comment: Then make sure you have the scripts in the correct order (`jquery` first, then `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax`) and that you have not included the scripts more than once (and don't change your original question - append edits instead otherwise existing answers and comments make no sense!)

Comment: I forgot to add type="text/javascript" to the script. It's working now thank you